# How to make a transparent container stand out from the background?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my containers transparent and still want them to easily standout from the background color, just like below image. (this is PSD image)

[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B1yD.jpg)

I tried wrapping `Container` inside a `Material` widget like this:

```
class customBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const customBar({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 2,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 65,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          //color: Color(0xff0a4873),
        ),
        child: Text(
          '',
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but it gives it too much `elevation`

also tried using a solid color but that doesn't give me what is required either,

```
Expanded(
  flex: 4,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        customBar(),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 60,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Color(0xff0a4873),
          ),
          child: Text(
            '',
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

here is the output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr5eA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`Material` is not necessary. If you want to adjust color transparency either use `Colors.YOUR_COLOR.withOpacity(0.0 .. to .. 1.0)` or `Color.fromRGBO(RED, BLUE, GREEN, 0.0 .. to .. 1.0)`
Examples:

```
Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3);
// OR
Color.fromRGBO(50, 45, 220, 0.3);
```

**Edit**
You can simplify your layout like this.

HomePage

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomContainer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // other widgets and your containers here
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your CustomContainer Widget

```
class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  CustomContainer({this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF1187be),
            Color(0xff061465),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but is there a way to make it a bit opaque without adding additional colors? I am using a gradient for my background and want it to be shown in container bars as well, adding color to the container kills this.

Comment: Decrease considerably the opacity of the color to fit your need. You can for instance use `Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1)`

Comment: my widget tree is like this `Container`>`Scaffold`>`Container(1)`. Parent container has a gradient which is inherited by `Scaffold` and then the `Container` in question doesn't have any background color at all, it inherits the background color from Scaffold which inherits it from parent container, so Question is how can I increase or decrease the opacity if don't have a color added to this container?

Comment: Why `Container >> Scaffold >> Container` ? You could use directly `Container >> Container`

Comment: using `Scaffold` for `AppBar`, here's the complete code in pastebin [link](https://pastebin.com/VsQ0ALmu)

Comment: hi again! sorry, I've been ill and wasn't able to continue work, but your edit doesn't fit in what I'm trying here, first I'll have to add separate color to `AppBar` if I enclose `CustomContaine`r insider `Scaffold`, 2nd it still doesn't answer what I originally asked "how can I put a `container` inside a bigger `container`" in such a way that small `container` is visible but inherits the `background` from the bigger `container`.